# Mariadb encryption

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.2

I have a requirement to encrypt certain column of DB tables. Going through the links, have followed the below steps:

In /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
plugin-load-add = file_key_management
file_key_management_filename = /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc
file_key_management_filekey = /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key
file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = AES_CTR
```

Restarted the mysql

```
service mysqld restart
```

But i m unable to see the plugin added.

Executed the following mysql commands:

```
MariaDB [TestEncr]> CREATE TABLE table1 (col1 INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, secret CHAR(200)) ENGINE=InnoDB ENCRYPTED=YES;
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `TestEncr`.`table1` (errno: 140 "Wrong create options")

MariaDB [TestEncr]> install soname 'file_key_management';
ERROR 2 (HY000): Cannot decrypt /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc. Wrong key?
```

Unable to understand what is wrong???

Comment: Make sure you have `log-error` set in your .cnf file in the `[mariadb]` or `[mysqld]` sections. `log-error` doesn't have to specify a file, but it doesn't hurt. Then restart the `mysqld` service. Then check for clues in your MariaDB `*.err` file, which is usually in your datadir, which is usually `/var/lib/mysql/`. Does that have any relevant error or warning messages? Also, be sure to read the MariaDB documentation about the [File Key Management Encryption Plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/file-key-management-encryption-plugin/).

Comment: Also, what do you get from `SHOW PLUGINS SONAME WHERE Name LIKE 'file_key_management';`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/file-key-management-encryption-plugin/) correctly, you need to prefix the value of [`file_key_management_filekey`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/file-key-management-encryption-plugin/#file_key_management_filekey) with the literal `FILE:` in order for the subsequent part of the value to be interpreted as *a file path containing the password*, as opposed to being interpreted as *the actual password*. So in your case it should be:

```
file_key_management_filekey = FILE:/etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key
```